# Generating equations from factors in R

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R, and I am trying to create a new column, which is one column minus another column. For example:

```
price <- c("$10.00", "$7.15", "$8.75", "12.00", "9.20")
quantity <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
price <- as.factor(price)
quantity <- as.factor(quantity)
df <- data.frame(price, quantity)
```

In my actual data set, all the columns imported as factors. When I try to create the new column I get this:

```
diff <- price - quantity
In Ops.factor(price, quantity): - not meaningful for factors
```

I have tried to coerce the data to numeric using as.numeric(df), as.numeric(levels(df)), as.numeric(levels(df))[df], and setting stringsAsFactors to false, but the data gets converted to NAs. Data.matrix changes the values. Is there another way to get the above equation to work? Thanks!

Comment: Do some of your values actually have `$` symbols there? If so, they won't be read as numeric values. You'll need to strip those out first and convert to numeric if you want to do calculations on them.

Comment: `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` will stop strings getting converted to `factor`s, it won't force something that is already a `factor` into `character` strings.

Comment: Why is `quantity` being used as a factor in your data?  That doesn't seem right.  Actually, these are both meaningful numeric values so neither should really be a factor.

Comment: Hi Richard, it just imported that way. I have no idea why.

Comment: @123hwc.  As mentioned earlier by thelatemail, when you read the dataset, use `read.table("file.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)`

Comment: There are actually a bunch of doplicates out there. The presence of "$", commas, or "%" will prevent `as.numeric(.)` or `colClasses="numeric"` from behaving as naively expected, but there are a variety of gsub strategies, some of  which can be neatly embedded in the input process.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 as.numeric(gsub("^\\$","", price))-as.numeric(as.character(quantity))
 #[1] 5.00 1.15 1.75 4.00 0.20
```

Or from `df`

```
 df$diff <- Reduce(`-`,lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("^\\$","",x))))
 df$diff
 #[1] 5.00 1.15 1.75 4.00 0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with factor columns, you could add a new `diff` column with `within()` and some type coercion

```
> within(df, {
      diff <- as.numeric(gsub("[$]", "", price)) - 
                  as.numeric(as.character(quantity))
  })
#    price quantity diff
# 1 $10.00        5 5.00
# 2  $7.15        6 1.15
# 3  $8.75        7 1.75
# 4  12.00        8 4.00
# 5   9.20        9 0.20
```

You may also consider going back and re-reading the data into R.  It's simple, and will make things a little easier.  Here's how you could do it and get the desired result that way.

Create a data file:  This won't be necessary for you, since you can just read the original file again.

```
> write.table(df, "df.txt")
```

Read the data into R, remove the `$` sign, and calculate the difference:

```
> df2 <- read.table("df.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df2$price <- as.numeric(gsub("[$]", "", df2$price))
> with(df2, { price - quantity })
# [1] 5.00 1.15 1.75 4.00 0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid "" and $ in price column and avoid converting them to factors if you want to do math operations on them:

```
price <- c(10.00, 7.15, 8.75, 12.00, 9.20)
quantity <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
df <- data.frame(price, quantity)

df$diff <- price - quantity

df
  price quantity diff
1 10.00        5 5.00
2  7.15        6 1.15
3  8.75        7 1.75
4 12.00        8 4.00
5  9.20        9 0.20
```